# Windows 2012 Remote Desktop for more than 2 simultaneous users

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to setup a Windows 2012 Server that allows for more than 2 users to access it through remote desktop at the same time.

I know I need User/Device RDP CALs for it and I already have 4 them installed/activated and they show up on the RD Licensing Manager, I also have the Remote Desktop Services role installed.

However whenever a third user tries to connect through Remote Desktop he is asked to disconnect another user.

I saw some similar questions being asked here but no answers unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2012, you need the entire environment to get close to a UI, the tool we all knew and at least like is gone.  The GUI is sort of available if you have the full environment with a connection broker.

You should have gotten a grace period after setup where you could use the terminal server, but after a period it has to talk to the license server, but there's no way to tell it where the license servers is like before.  You can do it with group policy - Administrative Templates\Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Licensing.

From there you can set the licensing mode and the licensing server.  The server should then see the licenses and go back to session host and not just administrative remote desktop.

Comment: Thanks E-Rock, it worked after I forced Per Device on the group policy. Much appreciated.